# Поворот background родительского элемента

Tags: android, android-xml, rotation

Я хочу повернуть background у LinearLayout на 180 градусов с:

[image: Тестовый пример]

На:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение у LinearLayout векторное, поэтому не исключаю ответы поворота векторной картинки ну или другим способом, желательно чтобы можно было менять программно поворот на 180 градусов в моем случае.
Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
          android:background="@drawable/tab_sharp">

<TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам не нужно делать это анимированно, тогда самый простой способ заготовить две картинки и просто менять их между собой. В инном случае лучше применить ObjectAnimator и второй layout с фоном:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(flBackGround, View.ROTATION, 180f)
animator.setDuration(2000)
animator.start()
```

Знакомство с аниматорами начните от [сюда](https://habr.com/ru/company/livetyping/blog/274135/) и от [сюда](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation)

P.S. Duration можно и вовсе выбросить, это время которое будет длиться ваша анимация.

P.S.S. Способов решения данной задачи Android предлагает достаточно много, всё зависит от желания и целей.

UPD: Если мы используем два layout, должно быть примено так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flBackGround"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_sharp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Я не проверял код, но по идее Button и TextView тоже будут перевернуты, а мне этого не надо.

Comment: @vering да, если вы будете переварачивать тот в котором у вас лежат ваши элементы, а я говорю о том чтобы под ваше поле положить ещё один layout по размеру существующего с вашим фоном (например frameLayout или constraintLayout) и вращать уже его